# Angular JS - Select box has a blank option at top

Tags: angularjs, html-select, angular-ngmodel

The problem I had was that the `select` had a blank `option` at the top even though the model had a value corresponding to the value of the first option.

JavaScript:

```
var MyApp, Day;

Day = (function() {
  function Day() {}
  Day.MON = 'Mon';
  Day.TUE = 'Tue';
  Day.WED = 'Wed';
  return Day;
})();

MyApp = angular.module('MyApp1', []);
MyApp.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.myDay = Day.MON;
  $scope.Day = Day;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp1">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    Current value: {{myDay}}
    <select ng-model="myDay">
      <option ng-value="Day.MON">
        {{Day.MON}}
      </option>
      <option ng-value="Day.TUE">
        {{Day.TUE}}
      </option>
      <option ng-value="Day.WED">
        {{Day.WED}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Output HTML:

```
...
Current value: Mon
<select class="ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="myDay"><option value="? string:Mon ?"></option>
  <option class="ng-binding" value="Mon" ng-value="Day.MON">
    Mon
  </option>
  <option class="ng-binding" value="Tue" ng-value="Day.TUE">
    Tue
  </option>
  <option class="ng-binding" value="Wed" ng-value="Day.WED">
    Wed
  </option>
</select>
...
```

Note that the model has the correct value and that there is a blank `option` added directly inside the `select` element.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ndLtLmrv/

There are many similar questions on StackOverflow but most of them seems to be caused by an uninitialised model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours of searching for an answer and debugging (since my actual code is a lot larger I tried many different things) I finally found the solution! It was really simple actually. All I had to do was to remove all the whitespace inside the `option` elements.

New HTML:

```
...
<select ng-model="myDay">
  <option ng-value="Day.MON">{{Day.MON}}</option>
  <option ng-value="Day.TUE">{{Day.TUE}}</option>
  <option ng-value="Day.WED">{{Day.WED}}</option>
</select>
...
```

This will give the expected output.

The reason why I didn't write like this from the beginning was that I was using HAML, which added the new line and indentation automatically. I solved this by adding a `<` to the `%option` (see [HAML whitespace removal](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_)).

I still don't see why this happened though as I have similar `select`s which work just fine even though they have whitespace inside the `option`. Now I've got a solution at least.

**EDIT:**

Now I think I know why the problem occured. It seems that angular compares the value in `ng-model` with the option `value`s before `ng-value` is evaluated. Since the options didn't have any `value`s, the model was compared to the content of the options instead. This explains why it didn't work in the first case (there's too much whitespace) while it worked when I removed the whitespace.

Thus, the solution I proposed here only works if the content of the `option` is the same as its `value`. By manually adding a `value` the problem is solved.

This should be a more correct solution to the initial problem:

```
...
<select ng-model="myDay">
  <option ng-value="Day.MON" value="{{Day.MON}}">
    Mon
  </option>
  <option ng-value="Day.TUE" value="{{Day.TUE}}">
    Tue
  </option>
  <option ng-value="Day.WED" value="{{Day.WED}}">
    Wed
  </option>
</select>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple use of ng-options and ng-models to create the select box in angular js.

```js
var MyApp, Day;

Day = [{label:'Mon',value:'Mon'},{label:'Tue',value:'Tue'},{label:'Wed',value:'Wed'}];

MyApp = angular.module('MyApp1',[]);
MyApp.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.myDay = Day[1];
    $scope.Day = Day;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp1">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        Current value: {{myDay.value}}
        <select ng-model="myDay"
            ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in Day">
        </select>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I went with `option` elements instead of using `ng-options`.